# how to tweak the indent length

Tags: xetex, ctex

I want to indent some text in latex, this is my latex code look like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{ctex}
    
\begin{document}

（Sex:Female\indent{}Age:55）

\end{document}
```

the indent length is too wide, I want to tweak down the length. Then I have tried like this:

```
\setlength\parindent{0.5cm}
```

the width of the indent seems did not changed. What should I do to tweak the length small?

Comment: Why are you using `\indent` (which, incidentally, doesn't relate to the length parameter `\parindent`)? I suggest you use `\hspace{<some length}`, as in, say, `\hspace{3mm}`.

Comment: Did you try other values? The indentation *did* change but not too mach. The default `\parindent` is `15pt`, while 0.5cm` corresponds to `14.22636pt`.

Comment: @Mico That's not quite true. In horizontal mode `\indent` adds an empty box whose width is `\parindent`. But of course I agree with the `\hspace` suggestion.

Comment: @campa - Thanks for setting me straight on this. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you run

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
X\indent X

\setlength{\parindent}{.5cm}
X\indent X
\end{document}
```

you'll get

[image]

so there is definitely a difference. Why so small? Unhappy coincidence:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
(\the\parindent)(\the\dimexpr.5cm)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Choose a different value. However, as Mico pointed out in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/703460/how-to-tweak-the-indent-length#comment1750002_703460) you should rather use `\hspace` to add horizontal space in text. (BTW I strongly suspect that you should actually  use a table...)

Comment: +1 for your BTW